# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'HotelInfo' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, for-loop, typeerror

```
 //an ajax call to the api           
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost:8080/activitiesWithRealData?location=%22SEA%22&startDate=%2205-14-16%22&endDate=%2205-16-16%22&theme=%22food%22",
    dataType: 'JSON', type: 'GET',
    success: function (data)
    var viewModel;
    if(data) {
    viewModel = new dealsPageModel(data);
    var idList = "";
    for (var i = 0; i< data.packageDeal.length; i++)
    {            
    if (i == data.packageDeal.length -1)
    { idList += data.packageDeal[i].hotelId;
    }            

    else
    {idList += data.packageDeal[i].hotelId + ',';
    }
    }

    var searchUrl = "http://terminal2.expedia.com/x/hotels?hotelids=" + idList +      "&apikey=6weV4ksGIJ5eQhd58o2XTDwVo35lZf2S";
     //another call to another api to return hotel specific info           
    jQuery.get(searchUrl, function (  )
    {

    for(var i=0; i<viewModel.dealList.length; i++)
    {
    var hotelId = viewModel.dealList[i].hotelId;

    for(var i=0; i<data.HotelInfoList.HotelInfo.length; i++)
    {
    var url = HotelInfoList.HotelInfo[i].ThumbnailUrl;
    var name = HotelInfoList.HotelInfo[i].Name;
    }

    // Get the hotelid from the current deal
    // Loop through the hotelinfolist.hotelInfo and find out the url for the hotel idList
   //Loop through the hotelinfolist.hotelInfo and find out the name for the hotel

    viewModel.dealList.push(new deal(data.packageDeal[i], url, name));
    }
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
    }
    }
    })
    });
```

Comment: Here is my question:  I am trying to loop through the HotelInfoList however I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'HotelInfo' of undefined. Please advise ASAP.

Comment: I think you have to receive 'data' here `jQuery.get(searchUrl, function (  )`

Comment: can you add the structure of response data

Comment: It means that your object `HotelInfoList` is missing that property called `HotelInfo`. You expect it to be there, but I guarantee if you console.log it, it will not be there.

Answer (score 1):

You loop through `data.HotelInfoList.HotelInfo` but operate on `HotelInfoList.HotelInfo[i].ThumbnailUrl`. The `data.` at the beginning is missing.

Also, place `data` in the callback function in `jQuery.get`:

```
jQuery.get(searchUrl, function(data){
// …
```

Comment: thank you! the error is solved but we are now getting another:   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '10' of undefined in the line viewModel.dealList.push(new deal(data.packageDeal[i], url, name));

Comment: @Vick I would strongly recommend indenting your code. You would have long noticed that this line is outside of your `for` loop and `i` is equal to `data.HotelInfoList.HotelInfo.length` at this point. Please don’t ask follow up questions in the comments. Try to fix it yourself first and only then ask a new question if you truly can’t fix it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

your data is in data.HotelInfoList not in HotelInfoList

your loop should be like this

```
  for(var i=0; i<data.HotelInfoList.HotelInfo.length; i++)
   {
    var url = data.HotelInfoList.HotelInfo[i].ThumbnailUrl;
   var name = data.HotelInfoList.HotelInfo[i].Name;
   }
```